# Redis Cluster default behaviour on read operations

Tags: redis

In a redis cluster what is the default behaviour for the read operations that happen? Does a client read from the master? I know that a client writes/updates/deletes to the master but what about read operations? If the default behaviour is to read from the master node how can I configure it to read from the slave nodes instead?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on Redis client library. For Jedis/Lettuce, all operations(CRUD) will be send to corresponding master node, and slaves are only used for failover.

If you wan to implement READONLY slave, you need some customization on Redis client.

Comment: I am not using a redis library. I just fire up local cluster of redis though cli and I'm not sure about the default behaviour. What I want to know is whether the default behaviour of a master is to redirect get ops in slaves.

Comment: Redis master will not redirect traffic to slave by default.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation where you found this because I need to check how can i redirect the reads to slaves.

Answer (score 0):

> The default behavior of replica nodes in cluster-mode enabled clusters
> is to redirect all client read/write requests to an authoritative
> master node of the shard that belongs to the key's hash slot. The
> replica node serves the read request only if that shard belongs to the
> hash slot and a readonly command was initiated by the client. This
> means that the replica node processes the request only if readonly is
> issued by the client before the request. Otherwise, the request is
> redirected to the primary node of the shard that the hash slot belongs
> to.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elasticache-redis-client-readonly/

Comment: Yes but this is if a client directs a command to a replica node. What I want to achieve is when a master node gets a read operation to route it to one of its slave nodes in order to lighten the traffic of the master node.